# insufficient privileges SYS.DBMS_DDL

Tags: oracle, imp

I am trying to use the Oracle `imp` utility. A lot of good documentation exists but it seems that it is not possible or documented how to import with a regular user. It is assumed that `sys` will be used I think. Grant privileges for example using something like

```
GRANT execute ON sys.dbms_ddl TO myuser;
```

Which is suggested on some non-Oracle sites. Does not work. The error remains the same.

```
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1031 encountered
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DDL", line 361
```

What grants should I issue to authorize a user for `imp` utility?

Importing as SYSTEM also does not work. This user also does not have permissions to import.

```
[vagrant@jira ~]$ imp SYSTEM/oracle@jira file=/tmp/jira-oracle.dmp fromuser=jira touser=jira_restore

Import: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Oct 9 12:24:09 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Export file created by EXPORT:V12.02.00 via conventional path
import done in AL32UTF8 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 942 encountered
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
IMP-00023: Import views not installed, please notify your DBA
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

Has anyone used these utilities with some success? I don't think they are officially supported by Oracle.

They are shipped by Oracle strange enough. On Oracle website

> Instant client tools provides exp / imp utilities since v12.2.0.1.0.
>   Unrestricted download is available

But also on the documentation website of Oracle

> Original export is desupported for general use as of Oracle Database
>   11g

So it seems it can be both: distribute tools but not support them!

So I am reaching a conclusion here. Simple export / import of a schema is not so simple if at all possible when using Oracle. Contrary to statements made.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the file you are trying to import constains objects that you have no permission to create/alter.

try this:

```
GRANT IMP_FULL_DATABASE TO myuser;
```

or run the IMP utility as SYSTEM user (not the SYS, but SYSTEM).